Is it possible to impersonate a Windows security token with Debug permission when original program don't have debug permission
New to Windows, playing arround with the API used to debug a process:
HANDLE hprocess;
hprocess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid);
if (hprocess == nullptr)
{
    printf("Failed to open process %d\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
if (!DebugActiveProcess(pid))
{
    printf("Failed to debug process\n");
    return -1;
}

As long as I launch this program with admin right I can debug other program. But without admin right I can't debug. However, I can debug a simple test program I write and launch next to my "Debugger program" without admin right.
Searching for a way to enable debug privilege I found what seems to be the classic way of doing it:
BOOL SetPrivilege(HANDLE  hToken,            // access token handle
              LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege,     // name of privilege to enable/disable
              BOOL    bEnablePrivilege   // to enable or disable privilege
)
{
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
LUID             luid;

if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
                          lpszPrivilege,   // privilege to lookup
                          &luid))          // receives LUID of privilege
{
    printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}

tp.PrivilegeCount     = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
if (bEnablePrivilege)
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
else
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

// Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.

if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, (PDWORD) NULL))
{
    printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}

if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)

{
    printf("The token does not have the specified privilege. \n");
    return FALSE;
}

  return TRUE;
}

However it don't work with me and the error "The token does not have the specified privilege" is raised.
Looking forward on what my Privilege token have using this function:
void DumpTokenPrivilege(HANDLE hToken)
{
char buffer[4096];

DWORD size_ret = 0;
if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS::TokenPrivileges, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), &size_ret))
{
    printf("GetTokenInfo fail: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}

TOKEN_PRIVILEGES* privilege = reinterpret_cast<TOKEN_PRIVILEGES*>(buffer);
for (int e = 0; e < privilege->PrivilegeCount; e++)
{
    printf("Privilege: %d for LUID: %d%d\n", privilege->Privileges[e].Attributes,  privilege->Privileges[e].Luid.LowPart,  privilege->Privileges[e].Luid.HighPart);
    char  str[4096];
    DWORD strlen = sizeof(str);
    if (!LookupPrivilegeNameA(nullptr, &privilege->Privileges[e].Luid, str, &strlen))
    {
        printf("LookupPrivilegeNameA fail: %d", GetLastError());
        return;
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
}

Resulting in :
Privilege: 0 for LUID: 190
SeShutdownPrivilege
Privilege: 3 for LUID: 230
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
Privilege: 0 for LUID: 250
SeUndockPrivilege
Privilege: 0 for LUID: 330
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege
Privilege: 0 for LUID: 340
SeTimeZonePrivilege

The problem seems to be that my token don't have DebugPrivileges meaning I can not enable it.
My first question is: Can I without needing admin right have this privilege enable when I launch my program ?
Playing with token API I notice that I can get token of another process and Impersonate it in order to apply it  to my program. So I lookup for a security token with debug priv and I apply it to my thread using this code:
HANDLE token = NULL;
HANDLE ph                 = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, true, pid);
BOOL res = OpenProcessToken(ph, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED | TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &token);
if (!res)
{
    token = (HANDLE) NULL;
}
if (token)
{
   if (HasDebugPriv(token))
   {
      auto thread = GetCurrentThread();
      HANDLE new_token = nullptr;
      if(!DuplicateTokenEx(token, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, nullptr, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL::SecurityDelegation, TOKEN_TYPE::TokenImpersonation, &new_token))
      {
          printf("Failed to set DuplicateToken: %d\n", GetLastError());
          return FALSE;
      }
      auto result = SetThreadToken(&thread, new_token);
      if (!result)
      {
          printf("Failed to set ThreadToken: %d\n", GetLastError());
          return FALSE;
      }
      return TRUE;
   }
 }

This code don't  return error however when I try to open my acquire my token to dump privilege and see that I got Debug privilege as intended:
HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
HANDLE hToken;

if (OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY , &hToken))
{
    DumpTokenPrivilege(hToken);
    ...

However OpenProcess Token failed with ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL (I did try to change SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL when invoking DuplicateTokenEx).
My second question: I'am trying to do something impossible ? Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the Windows API?

Without SeDebugPrivilege explicitly granted to your user account or process, it is not possible to enable it programmatically. Even if you manage to obtain a token with SeDebugPrivilege (e.g., through exploitation), the kernel enforces strict access checks that prevent non-admin processes from performing privileged operations.

Thanks for awnser, my program don't  have SeDebugPrivilege when I dump privilege of my current process token. I did write a simple infinite loop test program, compiled it in debug mode and launching it. Trying to debug this process without admin right work fine. None of both program have SeDebugPrivilege in theres token. Why can I stil l debug it when I can't debug other's ? Also if you have some kind of documentation about all this I would really appreciate if you could share it. Thanks

Moreover, how my IDE can attach and debug program without admin right ? Best regard

The reason you can debug your own test program (even without admin rights or SeDebugPrivilege) is that the security context of the debugger and the debuggee are the same. In this case, Windows permits debugging since it does not require escalated privileges. And IDEs like Visual Studio can debug processes without admin rights because they are typically debugging child processes started within the same user session and with the same security context.

And here is a good entry point to follow the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-control

Thanks for your awnser. I did not look at the doc yet so feel free to not awnser this question but what determine security context of a launched application ?  I mean when opening Visual studio (without admin right) I can attach debugger to whatever I want ( chrome in my example) without any issue. Why Visual studio have not the same security context than my custom program ? Is it related to binary location or trusted application ?

No prob mate, always happy to answer questions and provide help ;) The security context of a program is influenced by 1. privileges granted to the user who launched the application 2. token attached to the process determines its privileges 3. application manifest and policies (many IDEs use that at allows debugging scenarios under specific permissions 4. execution method (ie what happens with 'run as admin'). Your custom program likely lacks certain configurations or privileges that VS has. and VS has some built-in mechenisms directly with the windows api which can bypass some restrictions

VS doesn’t rely solely on SeDebugPrivilege. Instead, it uses a combination of
process ownership (same user context) and
debug APIs that allow limited debugging without requiring the privilege
